# Conditional CDF

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are independent and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

$Z=\arctan(\frac{Y}{X})$ and $Z$ is restricted between $[0,2\pi)$.

Given that $A=0 \leq Z\le \pi/4$ , what is the conditional CDF of $X$ given $A$ $F_{X|A}(t)$?

**My Attempt:**

I found the CDF of $X$ (I don't know it is necessary or not). Then I found the conditional CDF of $X$ given $A$ as $x^2$ between $0$ and $1$. Is this correct?

Comment: Duplicate of same question by same author:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96493/conditional-cdf

Comment: That link does is invalid - question deleted by author

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
Note that $Z = \arctan(Y/X)$ means $\tan Z = Y/X$. The event $A = Z \in [0,\pi/4]$ means
$$Y/X = \tan Z \in [0, 1] \Leftrightarrow Y \leq X.$$

So what is the conditional probability that $X \leq x$ given that $Y \leq X$?

**Edit**
$$
\mathbb{P}[X \le x | Y \le X]
 = \frac{\mathbb{P}[X \le x, Y \le X]}{\mathbb{P}[Y \le X]}
 = \frac{\mathbb{P}[X \le x, Y \le x]}{\mathbb{P}[Y \le X]}
 = \frac{x^2/2}{1/2} = x^2.
$$

Comment: I did that and found it as $x^2$. Is this right? @gt6989b

Comment: @Someone i think so, made the edit